# Unknown Error with either Wamp Wamp

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver

I newly installed Wamp 3.0.6 today and created user and pass to phpmyadmin which has all privileges.

I tested the installation with a simple PHP script:

```
<?php echo "hello"; ?>
```

and all seemed well. However when introducing braces (`}` or `{`), I get a syntax error:

```
<?php 
    $a = 1; 
    if ($a > 1){ 
        echo "There's more than 1";
    }
?>
```

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in C:\wamp64\www\tickets\test.php on line 4.

This error is occurring anytime a brace is used. Since **this *is* syntactically valid PHP** (as confirmed by [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/cKl1V)), I suspect something may be wrong with my wamp-server installation.

Any idea what's wrong here?

I have just now uninstalled and installed Wamp again. And the same thing.

I can do a simple  or

Any help would be much appreciated as this is getting on my nerves.

Comment: [Works for me!](https://3v4l.org/uSE3a) Maybe it's something else?

Comment: I appreciate you see this as a duplicate but no php script works that includes braces. Only a a standard echo  or phpinfo. That's it. I'm trying to establish if its something that needs fixing on Wamp?

Comment: Interesting. I've **aggressively** edited your question to reflect that. Please feel free to [edit] further if I've done something wrong. Voting to reopen this, since syntax isn't the issue here.

Comment: @HPierce But the point is its not reproducible. At least not on my WAMPServer v3.0.6

Comment: All I can think of is that there is some minor corruption in your source file. Delete that script completely and recode it from scratch. I suggest you do not use `notepad` as an editor, if thats what you were doing, download `notepad++` its free and a very decent code editor

Comment: @HPierce Ooo nice SO got a spell checker at last

Comment: Maybe they are using Word as an editor?

Comment: I was using Dreamweaver. Also I was using notepad++